# Web browser control for Firefox/Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

Just like Microsoft Internet Explorer, there is web browser control functionality:

[Using MFC to Host a WebBrowser Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I want to inject Javascript in real to a local webpage opened in Chrome browser from my C++ app.
Is there anyway to accomplish this job?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Native Client](http://code.google.com/chrome/nativeclient/).

Comment: thank you Shaz, it sounds interesting. I thought there must be a simple way but anyway im gonna give it a try. I hope i can incorporate it in my project.

Comment: @Johnydep: Sure thing. I would explain it, but I've never used it myself. Probably because I don't even know C++ (yet) :P